# Text file manipulation using visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am looking for a way to take a text file that has 1 set of numbers per line and make a new text file that has taken the set of numbers and put them into 2 spaced out columns per line. Using **Visual Basic 2010**  Ex:

My First text file will look similar to this: test1.txt

1. 12345
2. 23456
3. 34567
4. 45678
5. 56789
6. 67890

But I would like to convert it to look like this and save it as a new file: text2.txt

1. 12345 23456
2. 34567 45678
3. 56789 67890

With more spacing in between the set of numbers. I have been struggling with this for about a week now and I have put myself back at square one with it. Thank you all for your time and hope you all have a good day.  Joe.

Here is my current code. I am embarrassed to say the least.  I am taking an exsisting file and formatting it to have a space between each line of numbers and then reading it into a richtextbox to convert it to a barcode font then saving it.  At that point I have no idea how to make the format the way I need it to be putting 2 sets of numbers on one line.

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles btnLoad.Click
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\test\serintest.txt"))
End Sub

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test\serscantemp.rtf"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t As Integer

    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString(t)

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

    For i = 0 To TextBox1.Text - 1

        'objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
        objWriter.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(i))

        objWriter.WriteLine("")
    Next
    objWriter.Close()

    Me.RichTextBox.LoadFile("C:\test\serscantemp.rtf", _
       RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

    RichTextBox.SaveFile("c:\test\barcodetext.rtf", _
       RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe,

Try this.

I am concatenating the numbers into a string variable and keeping a counter. If the counter = 2 then i write out the concatenated string to RichTextBox and clear counter and string variable

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\temp\serscantemp.rtf"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim c As Integer

    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString(t)

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

    c = 0
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To TextBox1.Text - 1
        c = c + 1

        If s > "" Then
            s = s & " "
        End If

        s = s & ListBox1.Items(i)

        If c = 2 Then
            objWriter.WriteLine(s)

            objWriter.WriteLine("")
            s = ""
            c = 0
        End If
        'objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))

    Next
    objWriter.Close()

    RichTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\temp\serscantemp.rtf", _
       RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

    RichTextBox1.SaveFile("c:\temp\barcodetext.rtf", _
       RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
End Sub
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you your code does exactly what I needed it to do. I appreciate your time and effort. You have really saved me on this

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that you might also want to try though almost the same as Ed's answer. Just call the routine from btnConvert click event. Also make sure to include Import System.IO

```
Private Sub Reformat(sourceFile As String, destFile As String)
    Dim arr As String() = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile)
    Dim s As String = String.Empty
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)()
    Dim iCtr As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arr(i)) Then
            s += arr(i) & " "
            iCtr += 1
            If iCtr = 2 Then
                lst.Add(s.Trim())
                iCtr = 0
                s = String.Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Trim()) Then
        lst.Add(s)
    End If

    File.WriteAllLines(destFile, lst.ToArray())
End Sub
```

By the way, this is my first post in SO. Just saying.

Comment: Yours worked perfect as well thank you. It is nice to see a couple ways to accomplish what I was failing at.  Thank you both for the great programming lesson.